# Eclipse auto generated equals() method

Tags: java, eclipse, equals

In eclipse's auto generated equals method, the first line compares reference equality

```
if(this == obj) return true;
```

As far as I know == is not really an equality check, it only checks if 2 references point to the same memory location. So why is it used?

Comment: If they _do_ point to the same object ("memory location"), they certainly are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have two references

```
Foo foo = new Foo("some value", " many parameter", 1, 2, 3, 5); 
Foo foo2 = foo;

if (foo2.equals(foo))
    // do something
```

Where `Foo` is a class with a bunch of fields that all need to be equal for object equality.

Comparing for reference equality early on saves you from having to check each field on the referenced objects because they are guaranteed to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

It's incredibly fast to check reference equality, so they might as well get it out of the way before moving on to more aggressive comparisons.